# Rewrite OpenCV method from Java to C++

Tags: java, c++, opencv

Could anyone tell me how does this piece of code looks like in C++ ? I'm really confused about java and it's representation of OpenCV.

```
public static MatOfPoint convexHull(MatOfPoint contour) {
    MatOfInt indexes = new MatOfInt();
    Imgproc.convexHull(contour, indexes);
    Point[] convexPoint = new Point[indexes.rows()];

    double x, y;
    int index;
    for (int i = 0; i < indexes.rows(); i++) {
       index = (int) indexes.get(i, 0)[0];
       x = contour.get(index, 0)[0];
       y = contour.get(index, 0)[1];
       convexPoint[i] = new Point(x, y);
    }

  return new MatOfPoint(convexPoint);
}
```

What I got so far is :

```
vector< Point > convexHull(vector< Point> & contour) {
  vector<int> indexes;
  convexHull(contour, indexes);
  Point[] convexPoint = new Point[indexes.size()];

  double x, y;
  int index;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < indexes.size(); i++) {
     //I really don't understant what's going on here  
  }
}
```

Also could anyone explain me please the body of for-loop of that java code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop populates the `convexPoint` array with points from `contour`, according to the indices returned by `Imgproc.convexHull`.

I'm not sure about Java, but in with the C++ API it's rather pointless, since [`cv::convexHull`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga014b28e56cb8854c0de4a211cb2be656) will happily do that for you when the output argument is `std::vector<cv::Point>`.

Then function then becomes

```
std::vector<cv::Point> convexHull(std::vector<cv::Point> const& contour)
{
    std::vector<cv::Point> result;
    cv::convexHull(contour, result);
    return result;
}
```

and it becomes somewhat questionable whether you even need it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't get why you want to convert a java code to c++ when that already exist. Looking at your posted code (if this is copied from somewhere, it will be very helpful to post link here)

```
public static MatOfPoint convexHull(MatOfPoint contour) {
    MatOfInt indexes = new MatOfInt();
    Imgproc.convexHull(contour, indexes);
    Point[] convexPoint = new Point[indexes.rows()];

    double x, y;
    int index;
    for (int i = 0; i < indexes.rows(); i++) {
       index = (int) indexes.get(i, 0)[0];
       x = contour.get(index, 0)[0];
       y = contour.get(index, 0)[1];
       convexPoint[i] = new Point(x, y);
    }

  return new MatOfPoint(convexPoint);
}
```

That code is calling opencv `Imgproc.convexHull(contour,indexes)`. It passes `MatOfInt` which means you will get indexes of points. Now if you look carefully at return value of the function, you can it is of type `MatOfPoint`, and that inside of the for loop, we are building the return object from point indexes. So the loop is just to convert from indexes to actual points. This is to describe what's happening in that code. But what makes all this strange is that opencv C++ (Not sure if opencv/java has this) has already the function to return actual points. You can check opencv official documentation on convexHull function [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=convexhull#convexhull)

Opencv c++ convexHull function signature is:

```
void convexHull(InputArray points, OutputArray hull, bool clockwise=false, bool returnPoints=true )
```

And the parameters description is:

> **Parameters**:
>       **points** – Input 2D point set, stored in std::vector or Mat.
>       **hull** – Output convex hull. It is either an integer vector of indices or vector of points. In the first case, the hull elements are 0-based indices of the convex hull points in the original array (since the set of convex hull points is a subset of the original point set). In the second case, hull elements are the convex hull points themselves.
>       **clockwise** – Orientation flag. If it is true, the output convex hull is oriented clockwise. Otherwise, it is oriented counter-clockwise. The assumed coordinate system has its X axis pointing to the right, and its Y axis pointing upwards.
>       **orientation** – Convex hull orientation parameter in the old API, CV_CLOCKWISE or CV_COUNTERCLOCKWISE.
>       **returnPoints** – Operation flag. In case of a matrix, when the flag is true, the function returns convex hull points. Otherwise, it returns indices of the convex hull points. When the output array is std::vector, the flag is ignored, and the output depends on the type of the vector: std::vector implies returnPoints=true, std::vector implies returnPoints=false.

As you can see from description of the parameters, if you pass **hull** as a vector of integers, you get back indexes. But if you pass a vector of points, you get back actual points rather than their indices. That's exactly what your posted function is doing. So rather than converting to c++, just use opencv c++ convexHull function directly by passing a vector of points.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to elaborate on my answer ;) There's your +1. Do upvote the question as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please tell me the name of translator which would translate java opencv code to c++ opencv code?

Comment: There exists an application where you can model some schema using boxes connected with edges(Drag and drop). Those boxes use OpenCV methods(for example import box for importing uses java imread etc) and are all written in Java(using wrapper JavaCV). The application also produces json file of structure of the schema so in that json there are all connections between boxes, all properties of boxes etc. So i'm creating an app which would produce the same C++ code to a given created schema. So basically output of my C++ code and output of that schema in that app would give me the same result.

Comment: @wxrw I didn't mean a tool exist to convert from java to c++ (Search on web if you wish to find if it exist). I wanted to say, since convexHull is originally written in C++, I found it strange to move from java to c++.